# Can't make a proper pseudo:checked for slider

Tags: css, slider

thank you for visiting my post. I need a little bit of hepl about slider in CSS.
I tried to set up pseudo:checked to scroll (not sure what is the right word) the image. It suppose to be set by % in margin-left, but it is not work for me. I tried to fix it by clumsy- manual way with pixel number. And it turn out very ugly.
Below is my code .Thank you for stopping by, and sorry for my bad English too

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slides">
                <!--radio button start-->
                <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
                <!--radio button end-->
                <!--slide img start-->
                <div class="slide first1">
                    <img src="./img/la.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="slide first2">
                    <img src="./img/ny.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="slide first3">
                    <img src="./img/chicago.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="slide first4">
                    <img src="./img/ny.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <!--slide img end-->
                <!--auto start-->
                <div class="navigation-auto">
                    <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                    <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                    <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                    <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
                </div>
                <!--auto end-->
                <!--manual nav start-->
                <div class="navigation-manual">
                    <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
                    <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>

                </div>
                <!--manual nav end-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #23E3C9;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.slides input {
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 2s;
}
.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

/*css for manual slide navigation*/
.navigation-manual{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 700px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.manual-btn{
    border: 2px solid #117f90;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}
.manual-btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.manual-btn:hover{
    background: #117f90;
}
#radio1:checked ~ .first1{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#radio2:checked ~ .first2{
    margin-left: -1514px;
}
#radio3:checked ~ .first3{
    margin-left: calc(-1514px * 2);
}
#radio4:checked ~ .first4{
    margin-left: calc(-1514px * 3);
}
```

What I tried: set up code for this

```
#radio1:checked ~ .first1{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#radio2:checked ~ .first2{
    margin-left: -1514px;
}
#radio3:checked ~ .first3{
    margin-left: calc(-1514px * 2);
}
#radio4:checked ~ .first4{
    margin-left: calc(-1514px * 3);
}
```

What I expected: margin-left: % value
Result: Not working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).